# Adicionar conteúdo na posição do cursor com CKEditor 4.5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Tenho um textarea onde será digitado determinado texto. Este texto poderá conter alguns campos específicos (tipo variáveis, que serão substituídos depois). Preciso saber como inserir estas "variáveis" no local específico onde preciso, por exemplo onde o cursor do mouse estava, pois todos os exemplos que vi até agora apenas incluem ao final do texto.

Um exemplo de como deveria funcionar:

"O **[nomeDoCliente]** está cadastrado no sistema desde **[dataCadastro]**"

As palavras em negrito seriam as "variáveis". Precisa pegar a última posição do mouse pois o usuário pode escolher onde inserir os campos, o que simplifica para ele.

Informação adicional: o textarea contém texto rico (CKEditor).

Conforme imagem abaixo, o usuário seleciona o "grupo" (p.e.: dados pessoais, dados da empresa, dados do veículo, etc) e depois o combo "campos" e populado segundo o grupo (p.e.: dados pessoais => campos: nome, idade, endereço, data de nascimento, etc). Ao selecionar um item no combo "campos", este item será adicionado no textarea, exatamente na última localização do mouse, que pode ser tanto no final do campo quanto no meio do texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do ckeditor? Se for o 4, creio que basta isso: `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertText( 'texto' );`

Comment: @Bacco versão 4.5

Comment: Testou [o método acima](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/161223#comment331581_161223)?

Comment: @Bacco, eu corrigi meu teste aqui e realmente sua sugestão funcionou - o erro foi meu. É exatamente isso que preciso, basta agora adaptar para minha necessidade (pegar o valor do campo, etc). O importante que a forma de fazer eu já descobri. Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método para inserção de texto arbitrário na posição do cursor é este:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertText( 'texto' );
```

Além do `insertText`, note que há os métodos `insertElement` e `insertHtml`, escolha o mais adequado para o contexto.

Mais detalhes no manual:

> http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertText

Answer (score 0):

Não estou a ver teu código, mas pode tentar:

```
var texto_var = document.getElementById("id_textarea").value = 
    "O" + nomeDoCliente "está cadastrado no sistema desde "+ dataCadastro;
```

Comment: a questão é que são diversas "variáveis" e elas ficarão disponíveis através de opções para o cliente selecionar qual quer em determinado momento. Da forma como você expôs ficou estático e nada funcional para o meu caso.

Comment: Para seu caso agora ou para o caso exposto na sua pergunta ? Lembrando que só você sabe qual o problema real a resolver, quanto mais específico você for, mais específica será a resposta...

Comment: Pro caso exposto na questão.

Comment: Qual o código em questão, tem como editar sua questão e colocar o trecho relevante ?

Comment: Não tem código. Até o momento tem apenas um textarea com CKEditor.

Comment: Talvez um diagrama ? Apesar que agora já tem um `textarea` e um modelo de funcionamento estático.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem e texto explicativo